# Unable to add comment. Clicking on add a comment taking me to top of the page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

I am not able to comment, when I am clicking on **add a comment** its jumping to the top of the page. Its happening everywhere on stack over flow (not on a single question)

**what I have tried as yet**

1. I have cleared cookies and cache
2. Uninstall re-install Chrome
3. Tried different web browsers

**Here is the Console Log**

> http://203.94.243.63:3000/getjs?lib=false&nadipdata=%22%7B%5C%22url%5C%22%3…C%5C%22reputations%5C%22%3A%5B1%5D%7D%22&screenheight=800&screenwidth=1280
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501
>   (Not Implemented)
>   http://203.94.243.63:3000/getjs?lib=false&nadipdata=%22%7B%5C%22url%5C%22%3…3A%5B1%5D%7D%22&screenheight=800&screenwidth=1280full.en.js?v=f5db443c1ac0
>   Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 501
>   (Not Implemented) http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.js
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   http://static.adzerk.net/Extensions/adFeedback.css Failed to load
>   resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   http://engine.adzerk.net/i.gif?e=eyJhdiI6NDE0LCJhdCI6MTcsImJ0IjowLCJjbSI6OT…ImJmIjp0cnVlLCJwbiI6ImFkemVyazYwOTkzMjY0MSJ9&s=u6WGz8x-1HNheTBJ8lGTLq7w_Eo
>   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: okay, It's 'add a comment'. I wanted to reply to someone's comment but when I am clicking on it its taking me to the top of the page @ShadowWizard

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have asked the resolution of 2 issues that I am facing on  SOF. **1** I am not able to add comment. **2** I am not able to format my question as the options are not available as shown in the screen shot. Please let me know whats so confusing in it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard so what do I suppose to do know delete and re-ask two separate question as its already mark done for no or some reason?

Comment: If the issues seem unrelated, then it's best to post them separately. You can edit this question to explain the first issue, then post another one with another explanation. Otherwise, it's hard for SE developers/community to triage both issues.

Comment: Better now, and this here is MSE, not specific to one site. (you have MSO for that.)

Comment: Anyway, click F12 and go to Console - what errors you see?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I have added the console log in the question. Many thanks

Comment: Looks like some malware or virus is messing with your broswers client side scripting. Run full virus scan and malware removal.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok!! thats a bad news!! I will do scan my mac.... by the way tons of thanks for your time

Comment: I sometimes run into this issue when the page or its JavaScript doesn't fully load.

Comment: Make sure all JavaScript files have loaded correctly. If some of them are blocked, this can very well be the result.